# Cassandra Batch Insert in Python

Tags: python, cassandra

I need to do a batch `INSERT` in `Cassandra` using `Python`.
I am using the latest `Datastax` python driver.

The `INSERTS` are batches of columns that will be in the same row. I will have many rows to insert, but chunks of the data will be in the same row.

I can do individual `INSERTS` in a `for loop` as described in this post:
[Parameterized queries with the Python Cassandra Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15683989/parameterized-queries-with-the-python-cassandra-module)
I am using parametrized query, values as shown in that example.

This did not help:
[How to multi insert rows in cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885238/how-to-multi-insert-rows-in-cassandra)

I am not clear how to assemble a parameterized INSERT:

```
BEGIN BATCH  
  INSERT(query values1)  
  INSERT(query values2)  
  ...  
APPLY BATCH;  
cursor.execute(batch_query)
```

Is this even possible? Will this speed up my `INSERTS`? I have to do millions. Even thousands take too long.
I found some Java info:
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/client-side-improvements-in-cassandra-2-0

Comment: Why do you need `batch` for that? Just insert your data using prepared inserts and you'll be fine

Comment: Won't the insert be faster if the INSERTs are done in BATCH ??? There are chunks of INSERTs that are in the same row. Will BATCH make a difference in localized writes? Although those INSERTs that are in the same row are contiguously INSERTed. Versus if Cassandra jumps around when INSERTing.

Comment: https://twitter.com/spyced/status/453640194076340224

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intro: Right now the DataStax Python driver doesn't support the CQL protocol in Cassandra 2.0 -- it's work in progress and betas will should up soon. At that point you'll be able to have a `BATCH` statement to which you can add bound prepared statements as needed.

Considering the above, the solution you could use is the one described in the post you've linked: prepare a statement that includes a `BATCH` with a series of `INSERT`s. The obvious downside of this solution is that you'd need to decide upfront how many inserts will be in your batch and also you'll have to split your input data accordingly.

Example code:

```
BATCH_SIZE = 10
INSERT_STMT = 'INSERT INTO T (id, fld1) VALUES (?, ?)';
BATCH_STMT = 'BEGIN BATCH'

for i in range(BATCH_SIZE):
  BATCH_STMT += INSERT_STMT

BATCH_STMT += 'APPLY BATCH;'
prep_batch = session.prepare(BATCH_STMT)
```

Then as you receive data you can iterate over it and for each `BATCH_SIZE` rows you bind those to the above `prep_batch` and execute it.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected that from the datastax post. Your answer helps though.

Comment: I believe this answer is now out of date

Comment: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.25/cqlengine/batches/

Answer (score 7):

Since version 2.0.0 of the driver, there is a [`BatchStatement` construct](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/query.html#cassandra.query.BatchStatement). If using the ORM, you can also use the [`BatchQuery` class](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/cqlengine/batches.html).

```
cluster = Cluster([sever_ip])
session = cluster.connect(keyspace)
insert_user = session.prepare('INSERT INTO table_name (id,name) VALUES (?, ?)')
batch = BatchStatement(consistency_level=ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM)
for i,j in some_value:
    try:
      batch.add(insert_user,(i,j))
      logger.info('Data Inserted into the table')
    except Exception as e:
      logger.error('The cassandra error: {}'.format(e))
session.execute(batch)
```